# Dynamic tableView cell in collection view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am unable to make dynamic increment of rows in table view (It is probably because I have added the table view in collection view) whereas in other situation I have practiced the similar code in table view only and it is working fine. 
I want to know the possible reasons and solutions as I am restricted to use the code in table view under collection view.

I am using auto layout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: please show your try .

Comment: self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
 self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 self.tableView?.reloadData()